# How to instruct dotnet publish command to fill in my web.config values?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core

I publish a .Net Core 2.2 project using this command `dotnet.exe publish -o "C:\temp\api" /property:Configuration=Debug`

However, if I inspect the `web.config` file it still has placeholders such as `%LAUNCHER_PATH%` and `%LAUNCHER_ARGS%`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout">
        <environmentVariables>
          <clear />
          <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Development" />
        </environmentVariables>
      </aspNetCore>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

When I deploy the app to IIS server (with the above `web.config`) I see this error in the EventViewer:

```
Application 'C:\inetpub\api\' failed to start. Exception message:
Executable was not found at 'C:\inetpub\api\%LAUNCHER_PATH%.exe'
```

Is there a way to instruct the `dotnet publish` command that I want `LAUNCHER_PATH` & `LAUNCHER_ARGS` placeholder variables to be replaced by `dotnet` and the `ProjetName.dll` respectively?

Comment: Is there any problem if you don't see that ? Basically I have used web.config with IIS and It automatically set for .net core site by the module.  Process those two environment variable.

Comment: Hi @dotnetstep, I updated my question and added the error I am seeing when I try to use the above `web.config` file